# Ionic 3, Firebase | Remove data from database

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

I want to remove a data from database. I already found key of child with

```
firebase.database().ref('Applications/' + 
   this.IDofLibrary).orderByChild('IDofUser').equalTo(input.IDofUser)
      .once('value').then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
                console.log(child.key)
                this.keyy = child.key // This line gave error ------        
        });
    });
```

As I said I already saw child's key in console of Google Chrome like picture where below ( Picture 1)

[image: Picture 1]

-LXQwVU8EFarKEsdNQtq is the key of my child.

But when I try to save it to a variable I took error like picture where top(Picture 1).

All codes on below. How can I remove this child?

```
  AcceptOrNot(input){
    this.once = true;
    const alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: input.nameOfUser +' ' + input.lastnameOfUser + 'onaylansın mı?' ,

       buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Onayla',
          handler: data => {


            this.database.list('Applications/' + this.IDofLibrary + '/').valueChanges().subscribe((data2) => {
                for(let item2 of data2){
                    if(this.once == true){
                        console.log("Once bilgisi : " + this.once)
                        console.log(item2.IDofUser  +  " ----" + input.IDofUser)
                      if(item2.IDofUser == input.IDofUser){
                            firebase.database().ref('Applications/' + this.IDofLibrary).orderByChild('IDofUser').equalTo(input.IDofUser)
                                .once('value').then(snapshot => {
                                    snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
                                        if(child.exists){
                                            console.log(child.key);
                                            this.keyy = child.key.toString;
                                        }

                                    });
                                });

                        this.database.list('Applications/' + this.IDofLibrary + '/').push({
                            Email : item2.Email,
                            IDofUser : item2.IDofUser ,
                            nameOfUser : item2.nameOfUser,
                            lastnameOfUser : item2.lastnameOfUser,
                            whichLibrary : item2.whichLibrary,
                            dateOfBorn : item2.dateOfBorn,
                            canBeRezerve : 'true',

                        });
                        this.once = false;
                      }
                     item2 = {};
                    }
                }
  })
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'Reddet',
          handler: data => {
            console.log('Saved clicked');
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    alert.present();
  }
```

Edit :[image: Informations of child]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the context of `this`? Why not just define and use a variable?

Comment: @Diodeus-JamesMacFarlane I edited the question , Can you check it?

Comment: The problem is `this` is undefined. Log it out: `console.log(child.key, this);`

Comment: This is not an variable. I used it for reach to keyy variable which is declared at same page. 
I declared like `keyy : any;`

Comment: And when you log it out, is it defined at that point?